# .Net MVC4 Action Method parameter is null from jqGrid post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have looked through many posts on this subject but so far I haven't resolved my problem. I am new to MVC / Jquery so I may have missed the answer.

I wish to return all rows from a jqGrid. I have used Oleg's example code for the jqGrid processing:

```
    sendData = function (data) {
        var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert("The following data are sending to the server:\n" + dataToSend);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Update", "WatchList")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataToSend,
            loadonce: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // remove error div if exist
                $('#' + grid[0].id + '_err').remove();
                alert("Updates Complete");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // remove error div if exist
                $('#' + grid[0].id + '_err').remove();
                // insert div with the error description before the grid
                grid.closest('div.ui-jqgrid').before(
                    '<div id="' + grid[0].id + '_err" style="max-width:' + grid[0].style.width +
                    ';"><div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding:0.7em;float:left;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +
                    'style="float:left; margin-right: .3em;"></span><span style="clear:left">' +
                    decodeErrorMessage(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) + '</span></div><div style="clear:left"/></div>');
            }

        $("#sendAll").click(function () {
            var localGridData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
            sendData(localGridData);
        });

    };
```

Fiddler output for the post is :

```
POST http://localhost:49323/WatchList/Update HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:49323
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:49323/WatchList/Edit
Content-Length: 3645
Cookie: __RequestVerificationToken=flUoW7U12gHRfOVMNiLu_tW4G_oVI4TwxvAYKOU9arGI014KWFKUKjUbgjbZStLb7n1TGmU22NtoQjAb26bmjcccjg8x6skcL1zbP_o2y5I1; .ASPXAUTH=D968251D718DEF7CA0C9D4A6BD2750F9923CBF554FC0B058772C753C4305682578C207F7367B6D61F80F84CBDCA5C130126AE2CC5E1715FA897122DEB68B3B40C86816C32A6F047891794A732F4A7A3499064220077793B5F1313813FFC21D01
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

[{"Date":"Fri 22 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"0"},{"Date":"Sat 23 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"1"},{"Date":"Sun 24 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"2"},{"Date":"Mon 25 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"3"},{"Date":"Tue 26 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"4"},{"Date":"Wed 27 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"5"},{"Date":"Thu 28 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"6"},{"Date":"Fri 29 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"7"},{"Date":"Sat 30 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"8"},{"Date":"Sun 31 March 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"9"},{"Date":"Mon 1 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"10"},{"Date":"Tue 2 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"11"},{"Date":"Wed 3 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"12"},{"Date":"Thu 4 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"13"},{"Date":"Fri 5 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"14"},{"Date":"Sat 6 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"15"},{"Date":"Sun 7 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"16"},{"Date":"Mon 8 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"17"},{"Date":"Tue 9 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"18"},{"Date":"Wed 10 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"19"},{"Date":"Thu 11 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"20"},{"Date":"Fri 12 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"21"},{"Date":"Sat 13 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"22"},{"Date":"Sun 14 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"23"},{"Date":"Mon 15 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"24"},{"Date":"Tue 16 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"25"},{"Date":"Wed 17 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"26"},{"Date":"Thu 18 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"27"},{"Date":"Fri 19 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"28"},{"Date":"Sat 20 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"29"},{"Date":"Sun 21 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"30"},{"Date":"Mon 22 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"31"},{"Date":"Tue 23 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"32"}]
```

The parameter received by the controller is null?  I don't have a model to bring the data directly into as the grids columns are dynamically created so I need to parse the raw data. What do I need in my controller action to get hold of the post data?

Comment: please include the action method in your question

Comment: All I have done with the action result is to attempt to see the returned value :

Comment: All I have done with the action result is to attempt to see the returned data e.g. public ActionResult WatchList([FromBody]string rows) {  and other variations but only ever get null. I thought that I may be able to grab the data from the FormCollection but it doesn't appear there either. I guess I need to know more about MVCs parameter mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying like this:

```
 function sendData(data) {
        var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert("The following data are sending to the server:\n" + dataToSend);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("WatchList", "Update")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {griddata:dataToSend},
            loadonce: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // remove error div if exist
                $('#' + grid[0].id + '_err').remove();
                alert("Updates Complete");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // remove error div if exist
                $('#' + grid[0].id + '_err').remove();
                // insert div with the error description before the grid
                grid.closest('div.ui-jqgrid').before(
                    '<div id="' + grid[0].id + '_err" style="max-width:' + grid[0].style.width +
                    ';"><div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding:0.7em;float:left;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" ' +
                    'style="float:left; margin-right: .3em;"></span><span style="clear:left">' +
                    decodeErrorMessage(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) + '</span></div><div style="clear:left"/></div>');
            }

        $("#sendAll").click(function () {
            var localGridData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
            sendData(localGridData);
        });

    };
```

**In controller**:

```
public ActionResult WatchList(string griddata) { 
........
}
```

Comment: Your change moved me forward but then an issue with serialization (see above). This comment section wasn't large enough for my reply so I added a further answer figuring that it would answer yours in conversational mode. It didn't and my answer appears before yours. I obviously need to understand better how to use Stack Overflow threads.

Comment: And one more thing I noticed is, your action name is watchlist and the url you provided is Watchlist/Update. plz modify it to  "url: '@Url.Action("WatchList", "Update")'" (I have corrected it now in this answer.)

Comment: Finally, I have the data. The change I made following your advice was to change the content type to: contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" It looks like this is needed to match the encoding that is taking palce automatically. I assume the json content type is not needed by MVC, just the data type.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. This problem is solved. No doubt there are plenty to come. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Acceptance or an upvote to the answer would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your change must be close because the data is now being recognised but with the error

```
 Invalid JSON primitive: griddata.]
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: griddata.

[ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: griddata.]
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject() +915
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth) +597
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) +108
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) +211
   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(String input) +86
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext controllerContext) +298
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +123
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory) +59
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +171
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +460
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) +360
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() +85
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +154
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +199
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +978
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +523
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +83
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +501
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +417
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +373
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I have noticed that if I use the original code:

```
    data: dataToSend,
```

the post data shows in Fiddler as :

```
[{"Date":"Fri 29 March 2013","id":"0"},{"Date":"Sat 30 March 2013","id":"1"},{"Date":"Sun 31 March 2013","id":"2"},{"Date":"Mon 1 April 2013","id":"3"},{"Date":"Tue 2 April 2013","id":"4"},{"Date":"Wed 3 April 2013","id":"5"},{"Date":"Thu 4 April 2013","id":"6"},{"Date":"Fri 5 April 2013","id":"7"},{"Date":"Sat 6 April 2013","id":"8"},{"Date":"Sun 7 April 2013","id":"9"},{"Date":"Mon 8 April 2013","id":"10"},{"Date":"Tue 9 April 2013","id":"11"},{"Date":"Wed 10 April 2013","id":"12"},{"Date":"Thu 11 April 2013","id":"13"},{"Date":"Fri 12 April 2013","id":"14"},{"Date":"Sat 13 April 2013","id":"15"},{"Date":"Sun 14 April 2013","id":"16"},{"Date":"Mon 15 April 2013","id":"17"},{"Date":"Tue 16 April 2013","id":"18"},{"Date":"Wed 17 April 2013","id":"19"},{"Date":"Thu 18 April 2013","id":"20"},{"Date":"Fri 19 April 2013","id":"21"},{"Date":"Sat 20 April 2013","id":"22"},{"Date":"Sun 21 April 2013","id":"23"},{"Date":"Mon 22 April 2013","id":"24"},{"Date":"Tue 23 April 2013","id":"25"},{"Date":"Wed 24 April 2013","id":"26"},{"Date":"Thu 25 April 2013","id":"27"},{"Date":"Fri 26 April 2013","id":"28"},{"Date":"Sat 27 April 2013","id":"29"},{"Date":"Sun 28 April 2013","id":"30"},{"Date":"Mon 29 April 2013","id":"31"},{"Date":"Tue 30 April 2013","Night":"False","Morning":"False","Afternoon":"False","Evening":"False","id":"32"}]
```

if using

data: {griddata:dataToSend},

the data shows in Fiddler as :

```
griddata=%5B%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Fri+29+March+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%220%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sat+30+March+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sun+31+March+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Mon+1+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%223%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Tue+2+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%224%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Wed+3+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Thu+4+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%226%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Fri+5+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%227%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sat+6+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sun+7+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%229%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Mon+8+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2210%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Tue+9+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2211%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Wed+10+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2212%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Thu+11+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2213%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Fri+12+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2214%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sat+13+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2215%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sun+14+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2216%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Mon+15+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2217%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Tue+16+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2218%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Wed+17+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2219%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Thu+18+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2220%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Fri+19+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2221%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sat+20+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2222%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sun+21+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2223%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Mon+22+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2224%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Tue+23+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2225%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Wed+24+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2226%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Thu+25+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2227%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Fri+26+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2228%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sat+27+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2229%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Sun+28+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2230%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Mon+29+April+2013%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2231%22%7D%2C%7B%22Date%22%3A%22Tue+30+April+2013%22%2C%22Night%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22Morning%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22Afternoon%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22Evening%22%3A%22False%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2232%22%7D%5D
```